# Jasmine Spy On a Typescript Class Get() or Set() function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine 2.9 and I have not have problems spying on a function whether it was public or private but I am having difficulty trying to spy on a `get` or `set` function on the class level.

```
private class RandomService {
  public dogsHealth = 0;

  private get personsFullName(): string {
    return firstName + lastname;
  }

  private set personsLocation(address: string, city: string, country: string): string {
    return address + city + country;
  }

  public get dogsFullName(): string {
    return dogFirstName + dogLastName;
  }

  public get isDogAlive(): boolean {
    return dogsHealth <= 0 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Solutions I tried:

```
spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue(true);
spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName').and.returnValue(true);
spyOn(RandomService, 'dogsFullName').and.returnValue(true);
spyOnProperty(RandomService.dogsFullName, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue(true);
```

Currently I have not found a solution to this online but will continue looking. I know the get or set functions creates a variable so I thought perhaps solution 4 would have worked but still no.

### Update

(The code above is also updated).

Trying the update to return a string and using the following jasmine give me an error:

```
spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue('Frank');
```

`Expected a spy, but got 'Frank'`

As well as for the function `isDogAlive` I get the following:

```
<toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got true.
```

I understand it is giving me the correct value but if I `spyOn` it then should it not be a spy?

Comment: Your class seems to be a little off. I don't think Typescript has private modifiers at a class level. And a setter needs to have a single argument to work normally and shouldn't return a value. Also, if those are properties in the methods, then they should have `this` attached to them. Is that the actual class you're trying to test, or a random example? The first solution should by all means work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of returning a boolean value of true, try to return something like "frank". The return value is most likely expecting a string value rather than a boolean, which would be the cause of the issue.

```
let spyTemp = spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue("frank");
```

then

```
expect(spyTemp).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I have updated my question. String does return the value. However I get an erorr about it not being a spy? I added types to the functions to say whether it is string or boolean.

Comment: Yes same error. Getting the value is nice but I want to test it was called.

Comment: Could the service class being private have anything to do with it?

Comment: No changing to public made no difference.

Comment: Interestingly this worked.  `let spyTemp = spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue("frank");`

Comment: From there I do `expect(spyTemp).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: Strange. But in theory, yes, if you want to test that specific function in the service then you could verify that it was called and returned the correct value.

Comment: If you update your answer with that option as well I will mark it correct.

Comment: How to spy on setting a property?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options for you:

```
spyOnProperty(RandomService.prototype, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue('ben');

// or
service = new RandomService();
spyOnProperty(service, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue('ben');
```

Or if your method is static on the class:

```
export class RandomService {
  static dogFirstName: string;
  static dogLastName: string;

  public static get dogsFullName() {
    return RandomService.dogFirstName + RandomService.dogLastName;
  }
}

spyOnProperty(RandomService, 'dogsFullName', 'get').and.returnValue('ben');
```

Comment: Hello @Wingnod. I tried yours as well but get the same issue. As well as the variable does not exist on prototype error.

Comment: I'm just curious, but it seems like you should be getting typescript compiler errors in your typescript - http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ - I hope you don't mind me asking, but are you doing something to ignore the compiler errors? It doesn't seem like your class is valid. I know it's not related to the question itself, but I'm very interested :)

Comment: I have not set and ignores. It is valid. During compilation it creates a variable with a get method not set, if you defined both it adds both. By default variables have a get and set function.

Comment: You've defined a setter (```personsLocation```) that returns a value, and doesn't have an argument. That's not really a setter, and Typescript should pick up on that. Javascript won't care, but semantically it isn't correct. Rather than a setter, it's a getter. However, if everything is fine for you, I will speak of it no longer :)